# Replication via Kafka vs. mysql events

Tags: mysql, apache-kafka, replication, database-replication, mysqlbinlog

I have a need to maintain a copy of an external database (including some additional derived data). With the same set of hardware, which one of the following solutions would give me faster consistency (low lag) with high availability? Assume updates to external database happen at 1000 records per second.

a) Create local mysql replica of an external db using mysql 5.7 replication (binary log file mechanism).

OR

b) Get real time Kafka events from external system, doing HTTP GET to fetch updated object details and use these details to maintain a local mysql replica.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first will almost certainly give you lower lag (since there are just two systems and not three). Availability is about same - Kafka is high availability, but you have two databases on both sides anyway.

The second is better if you think you'll want to send the data in real-time to additional system. That is:
MySQL1 -> Kafka -> (MySQL2 + Elastic Search + Cassandra + ...)

Comment: Thanks. My real use case is that if x changes in external system, say A, then my system, say B, needs to know. Then use x and some additional data associated with x, say X, to calculate y and send y to yet another external system, say C. X is obtained using heavy aggregated query on data store of external system A. Now the question was whether to create replica of A in B through native MySQL replication or don't do replication and rather do GET on change event for x to store in local replica before using aggregated query.

Answer (score 0):

I hate to answer questions with a 'just use this oddball thing instead' but I do worry you're gearing up a bit too heavy than you may need to -- or maybe you do, and I mis-read.

Consider a gossipy tool like serf.io .  It's almost finished, and could give you exactly what you may need with something lighter than a kafka cluster or mysql pair.